# Select SCP Copy

Tags: linux, bash, perl, ssh, scp

I've seen an example that used RSYNC and SSH to do this, however in my specific case I could not get this working - it gave me some error about protocol versions

I'd like to copy over all files of type `.sh`, `.jar`, `.war` from a directory structure over to a remote host that is a 2 hop (ssh with proxy) ssh away.

I'm not sure of the best way to do this.  Would it be with SCP or some sort of bash script?

#### What I know:

```
find . | grep "\.sh"
```

will give me a nice list of files and i can probably use `xargs` to do something with them.

I guess some options would be to create a `tar.gz` file and `scp` it over, or perhaps write a little bash script to do individual SCP-ing?

I came up with this terrible way to do this with perl but its REALLY slow

```
my $find = `find .`;

my $remote = "USER\@MACHINE:";

my $remotePrefix = "/devel/test";


my @files = split('\n', $find);

foreach (@files) {

    if (/(.*\/)([^\/]*\.sh)$/ or
        /(.*\/)([^\/]*\.jar)$/ or
        /(.*\/)([^\/]*\.war)$/
        ) {

        my $fullPath = $_;
        my $directory = $1;
        my $file = $2;
    

    # print "$fullPath => $directory   ||     $file\n";

    $cmd1 = qq(ssh USER\@MACHINE mkdir -p $remotePrefix$directory);
    $cmd2 = qq(scp $_ $remote$remotePrefix$_);


    `$cmd1`;
    `$cmd2`;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to create the matching directory structure on the remote end? It doesn't already exist?

Comment: Yes my script does this sort of

Comment: Yes, I saw that it did but I was checking that that was necessary. That requirement means you can't just use scp for this since it won't do that. Which means `tar` is likely the best option if you can't use something `rsync`.

Comment: Did you try setting `--protocol=...` on rsync to match the remote?

Comment: @meuh In the vast majority of cases the protocol mismatch error has nothing to do with `rsync` protocol, and is typically caused by the remote shell's profile printing things upon login for non-interactive shells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your filenames don't contain newlines, you can do it with `cpio(1)`:

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.sh' -o -name '*.[jw]ar' \) -print | \
    cpio -oa | \
    ssh "${USER}@${MACHINE}" "cd ${remotePrefix}; cpio -idm"
```

Answer (score 1):

kinda old post but i just had a similar task and after some research came up with this in bash, uses sshpass to allow inline ssh usage, the base dir exists on both local and remote server.  The new file directories will be created on the remote server. This is called like: `script fid src-base-dir`

```
#!/bin/bash

fid=$1;  
basedir=$2;

##myfiles are fixed 10 numeric files stored in respective directories starting at the 6th pos
##eg dir 1234560000 for files 1234560000.file - 1234569999.file

dir=${fid:0:6}0000;     ## modify for your directory type or use other shell substring  
fpath=$dir/$fid.file;   ## here you could expand bash to specify extensions or all eg $dir/$fid.{csv,jpg,js}

if [ -a "$basedir/$fpath" ]
then
    rDir=$(sshpass -e ssh -p <myport> <user>@<server> "ls '$basdir/$dir' 2>&1 > /dev/null ");
    if [[ ! -z $rDir ]];        
    then
        sshpass -e ssh -p <myport> <user>@<server> "mkdir '$basedir/$dir'";
        sshpass -e scp -P <myport> $basedir/$fpath <user>@<server>:"$basedir/$fpath";
    else
        sshpass -e scp -P <myport> $basedir/$fpath <user>@<server>:"$basedir/$fpath";
    fi
else
    echo $basedir/$fpath no exist!!
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

use [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign):

```
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host, user => $user);
$sftp->rput('.', $remote_prefix,
            wanted => qr/\.(?:sh|war|jar)$/);
```